# Unknown character � shown in JSP string variable

Tags: jsp

I use String variable in JSP to get login name in windows
While it displays properly in browser
An Unknown character � is shown when the string is passed as a value to a text box?
How to get rid of it?This is the code i use btw

<

```
%
  String username=null,remoteHost=null;
String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
if (auth == null)
{
  response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
  response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");
  response.flushBuffer();
  return;
}
if (auth.startsWith("NTLM "))
{
  byte[] msg = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(auth.substring(5));
  int off = 0, length, offset;
  if (msg[8] == 1)
  {
    byte z = 0;
    byte[] msg1 = {(byte)'N', (byte)'T', (byte)'L', (byte)'M', (byte)'S', (byte)'S', (byte)'P', z,(byte)2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z,(byte)40, z, z, z, (byte)1, (byte)130, z, z,z, (byte)2, (byte)2, (byte)2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z};
    response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(msg1));
    response.sendError(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    return;
  }
  else if (msg[8] == 3)
  {
    off = 30;

    length = msg[off+17]*256 + msg[off+16];
    offset = msg[off+19]*256 + msg[off+18];
    remoteHost = new String(msg, offset, length);

    length = msg[off+1]*256 + msg[off];
    offset = msg[off+3]*256 + msg[off+2];
    String domain = new String(msg, offset, length);

    length = msg[off+9]*256 + msg[off+8];
    offset = msg[off+11]*256 + msg[off+10];
    username = new String(msg, offset, length);

    out.println("<h2>Welcome:"+username+"</h2><BR>");
    //out.println("RemoteHost:"+remoteHost+"<BR>");
    //out.println("Domain:"+domain+"<BR>");
  }
}
%>
```

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem. Do you specify the character set for both JSP and HTML?

Comment: I have specified the code above..Could you help me out in this:)

Comment: That's not what was asked. How do you serve your document? Is there a charset declaration somewhere in the HTML HEAD? Is it in the HTTP headers?

Comment: Also, can you give us the output of `java.util.Arrays.toString(msg)`?

Comment: This is the o/p [78, 84, 76, 77, 83, 83, 80, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 24,0, 24, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 24, 0, -112, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 18, 0, 78, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 24,0, 96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -88, 0, 0, 0, 5, -126, 0, 2, 5, 1, 40, 10, 0, 0, 0, 15, 86, 0, 67, 0, 83, 0, 97, 0, 108, 0, 119, 0, 97, 0, 114, 0, 115, 0, 97, 0, 109, 0, 121, 0, 83, 0, 67, 0, 76, 0, 67, 0, 88, 0, 74, 0, 54, 0, 77, 0, 76, 0, 76, 0, 49, 0, 83, 0, -12, -106, 97, -99, -72, 54, -4, -121, 48, 91, 39, -56, -109, 31, -17, -108, 72, -100, 7, -79, 87, -10, 29, 15, 30, -13, 54, 122, -108, -23, 89, 118, -5, 124, -97,

Comment: This is the declaration used in HEAD section <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Answer (score 0):

The NTLM Authentication Scheme [alledgedly requires](http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html) that the strings are encoded using UTF-16LE for the type-3 message. You rely on the default charset to decode the bytes instead of explicitly specifying what charset you want to use. Don't! The platform may use any default charset.

You really should add a [`Charset`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) parameter:

```
String username=null,remoteHost=null;
String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-16LE");
/* ... */
{
    off = 30;

    length = msg[off+17]*256 + msg[off+16];
    offset = msg[off+19]*256 + msg[off+18];
    remoteHost = new String(msg, offset, length, charset);

    /* ... use ascii for every other string you build
     * that should be ASCII-encoded according to the
     * NTLM Authentication Scheme...
     */
```

Make sure `java.nio.charset.Charset` is imported in whatever way JSP does that.

---

That said, you might want to dump the raw contents of the decoded byte array somewhere (using `toString` from `java.util.Arrays`), so that you can make sure your input is sane. There's not much to go by here without this information.

Comment: Sorry, I looked at the type-1 message, while you are parsing the type-3 message. It seems you need to use UTF-16LE. Could you try my code again?

Comment: Still the same result:(Anyways I found a simple way to overcome this all I did was to replace that unknown character that occurs between each character with a space character and then replace that with empty string..now i am able to get the username without any issue..Here is my code:                                                                   String username=null,c1=null,c2=null,c3=null;                          char ck=' ';
c2=username.replace(username.charAt(1), ck);
c3=c2.replaceAll(" ", "");                                                      out.println("<h2>Hi:"+c3+"</h2><BR>");